# Add new key-value pair to struct-map in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have struct map like this

```
(def admin (struct-map person :first-name "Name" :last-name "Last name"))
```

So, now I would like to add new key-value pair to this map, and have it look something like

```
(def admin (struct-map person :first-name "Name" :last-name "Last name" :username "username"))
```

How do I do this?

I know that it won't be the same structure after this, but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not concerned with retaining the structure, `assoc` will add your new key-value pair.

```
(defstruct person :first-name :last-name)

(def admin (struct-map person 
             :first-name "Name" 
             :last-name "Last name"))

(assoc admin :username "username")
  ;=> {:first-name "Name", :last-name "Last name", :username "username"}
```

Comment: thanks. It worked just fine. Just one more question. If I `defstruct` person with username at the beggining, can I still gradually add key-value pairs?

Comment: Yes. You can treat struct-maps the same as hash-maps in most cases. The only differences being, the `accessor` function will throw an exception on keys not included in the `defstruct`, and you cannot `dissoc` a `defstruct` defined key. But, everything else should work like a hash-map.